# Split file by line removing the first field and using it as a name for the resulting piece

Tags: text-processing, split

I have such a text file:

```
19-198-0000 NORTHANGER ABBEY
19-198-0001 THIS LITTLE WORK WAS FINISHED IN THE YEAR EIGHTEEN O THREE AND INTENDED FOR IMMEDIATE PUBLICATION IT WAS DISPOSED OF TO A BOOKSELLER IT WAS EVEN ADVERTISED
19-198-0002 NEITHER THE AUTHOR NOR THE PUBLIC HAVE ANY OTHER CONCERN THAN AS SOME OBSERVATION IS NECESSARY UPON THOSE PARTS OF THE WORK WHICH THIRTEEN YEARS HAVE MADE COMPARATIVELY OBSOLETE
19-198-0003 THE PUBLIC ARE ENTREATED TO BEAR IN MIND THAT THIRTEEN YEARS HAVE
```

and so on. What I want is a way to create the same number of smaller text files as the lines in this initial one, their name to be the digits at the start of the line and their contents to be the rest.

For example, from the small snippet above:

```
19-198-0000.txt  would contain: NORTHANGER ABBEY
19-198-0001.txt  would contain: THIS LITTLE WORK WAS FINISHED IN THE YEAR EIGHTEEN O THREE AND INTENDED FOR IMMEDIATE PUBLICATION IT WAS DISPOSED OF TO A BOOKSELLER IT WAS EVEN ADVERTISED
19-198-0002.txt  would contain: NEITHER THE AUTHOR NOR THE PUBLIC HAVE ANY OTHER CONCERN THAN AS SOME OBSERVATION IS NECESSARY UPON THOSE PARTS OF THE WORK WHICH THIRTEEN YEARS HAVE MADE COMPARATIVELY OBSOLETE
19-198-0003.txt  would contain: THE PUBLIC ARE ENTREATED TO BEAR IN MIND THAT THIRTEEN YEARS HAVE
```

and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
while read -r tag line; do
    printf '%s\n' "$line" >"$tag".txt
done <text.in
```

When you read two variables with `read`, the first word is put in the first variable, and the rest of the line is put into the second.

What constitutes a "word" depends on the value of `$IFS`.  By default, `read` will split the line into words based on spaces, tabs or newlines.

The loop uses this to output the line (minus the first word, or "tag") to a file whose name is taken from the start of the line.

Comment: oh, didn't see you there :D thanks :) 15 sec interval with nearly the same result, that's cool.

Answer (score 1):

No need for `bash` at all:

```
awk '{file = $1".txt"; $1=""; print substr($0,2) > file; close(file)}' a_text_file
```

- Get `file` from the first column, append a `.txt` to that.
- Eliminate the first column.
- Print remaining columns (minus the otherwise leading space) into the `file`.

Meanwhile, about that `while` loop in `bash`:

```
$ (echo first; echo -n second) | while read line; do echo $line; done
first
$
```

Mmm, silent data loss. Better be sure there are *always* ultimate newlines, eh?

Comment: A line without a newline is not a line. Therefore `read` will not read it.

Comment: @Kusalananda: actually `read` does read an unterminated last line, but it returns 'error' (nonzero) status causing the `while` loop to not process it. OTOH `read` without `-r` and `echo` especially with `$line` unquoted will alter data containing backslash, whitespace other than single SP, and sometimes glob chars, and sometimes beginning with hyphen.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 Thanks for that. To get the `second` one could do `(echo first; echo -n second) | ( while read line; do echo "$line"; done; echo "$line" )` in this _specific_ case at least.

Answer (score 0):

managed to do it:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r filename content ; do
    printf '%s\n' "$content" >> "${filename}.txt"
done < some_file.txt
```